# How to recover from a stackoverflow ban at the beginning

Tags: discussion

Does stackoverflow have a "smart" process to recover from an initial ban.

For example if I have something interesting to share and I use stackoverflow may be I would gain 1 point (or whatever is named)

If one of the moderators consider my "beginner" answer or question innapropriate... it would give me -1 or -2 points.

The answer is deleted .  (qualified by only one smart moderator)
I cannot contact the moderator.
I cannot fix the answer. 
And I cannot send a new answer to correct the previous one. 
Great!!!!

How could I revert my status in stackoverflow in that situation?
Which is the fastest way?

Obviously I don't want to change identity but I would like to understand how I could contribute between this smart community.

Comment: This post doesn't reflect easily researched basics of how the site is run. It doesn't even reflect googling to find out what a "point" is called here. Or pointing a cursor on a display of "points". Appropriate research would be a start to "understand how I could contribute".

Comment: *"Obviously I don't want to change identity..."* -- Obviously if you *did* change identities, the site would catch on pretty quick, it was created by programmers after all, and that could lead to a permanent ban

Comment: You cannot be answered banned after a single answer.

Answer (score 14):

It would take me forever if I tried to exhaustively cover every situation in a general sense. I don't have forever, and I suspect you don't, either. So I'm just going to cover your specific situation, with a couple of general clarifications mixed in.

First, a single deleted (and/or downvoted) answer does not cause you to be banned. [Answer bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) reflect a *total* quality score, and take a bit more work to get yourself into than just one inappropriate answer.

You have, unfortunately, currently found yourself under an answer ban. This is due to your having three deleted answers, all of which have scores <= 0:

- [HDFS error: could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293446/hdfs-error-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-1/45147246#45147246)
- [Text search within transcripts of ALL youtube videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988560/text-search-within-transcripts-of-all-youtube-videos/61309666#61309666)
- [ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED in Page Speed Insight and Lighthouse chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304118/err-connection-failed-in-page-speed-insight-and-lighthouse-chrome-extension/62304165#62304165)

The first one on that list is so old that you've probably forgotten about it. It also has no downvotes. The middle one is a link-only answer with a score of −1 that was deleted a month or so ago. The last one was posted very recently and deleted by a moderator for being a link-only answer.

And that last answer is a nice segway into something that I wanted to say anyway: you can edit an answer *while it is in the deleted state*, improving it to comply with [our requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). At that point, you can then have it undeleted by a moderator (by flagging it). Since you've expanded that into an answer already, I've undeleted it. This is a good general strategy, and contradicts your statement in the question:

> The answer is deleted . (qualified by only one smart moderator) I cannot contact the moderator. I cannot fix the answer. And I cannot send a new answer to correct the previous one. Great!!!!

You *can* fix the answer, and if it's fixable, you *should*. You don't need to post a new answer, because you can fix the one you have. And you *can* contact a moderator, by raising a flag on your own post once you've edited it, pointing out that you have edited the answer to meet our standards, and requesting to have it undeleted.

I also want to point out that, even though the answer was deleted by a single moderator, that's almost never the only person who was involved. Members of the community flag posts as being inappropriate as a way of bringing them to moderators' attention. Moderators follow clear community guidelines on what counts as an answer when deciding whether or not to delete a post. It's not an arbitrary or opaque process.

> How could I revert my status in stackoverflow in that situation? Which is the fastest way?

Unfortunately, there is no "fast" way. It takes a while to get yourself a question or answer ban, because it requires several different low-quality posts. Making up for it requires fixing those low-quality posts, turning them into high-quality posts, which is often easier said than done. But it's really the only way. This is all described in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

> If one of the moderators consider my "beginner" answer or question innapropriate... it would give me -1 or -2 points.

I can't leave this one alone. First, downvotes have nothing to do with moderators. Moderators are the ones with shiny diamonds after our user names. We have many rules, but downvoting users questions isn't really one of them. Although we do exercise our voting privileges just like anyone else, the *vast majority* of votes—whether up or down—come from regular community members, not moderators, if for no other reason than because there are [so few of us](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Second, there's nothing wrong with "beginner" questions or answers. The problem is with answers that don't meet [our expectations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), answers that [the community is encouraged to flag as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer).

> Obviously I don't want to change identity but I would like to understand how I could contribute between this smart community.

Yes, please don't. Attempting to subvert a question ban by creating a new account is breaking the rules, and it may lead to even stiffer restrictions on your ability to use this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cody. It's a complete answer and let me understand the dynamic of StackOverflow.

Comment: And thanks for undeleting the answer. I've completed it but it has 2 downvotes, despite I consider a good workaround... But thanks for your change. Now I understand it better.

Comment: Yeah, there's little that can be done about the downvotes. They were cast when the answer was in its original form, and they were totally deserved/reasonable at that time. Unfortunately, it's not likely that those who originally reviewed the answer and voted on it will come back later to notice that it has been edited. Undeleting it is the best moderators can do. Perhaps others who see this question will think it deserves upvotes in its current form.